# How to model transformation of big collection to another collection via AggregateRoot?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, cqrs

## Problem

I modelled an entity **E** (AR) with a lot of VO as AgreggateRoot (AR)
I have **GROUP** (AR) that contains rules split E1 into subgroups and based on that, I can create another **SPLIT** (AR) that will hold results. This creates new entity **SPLIT_E** inside **SPLIT** based on **E** to holds border between AR's. We can make multiple AR splits, that won't change, but can differ in time as the original collection of **E** can be updated any time.

Currently, in one handler we collect all **E** that meet requirements (always same) and by iterating via that collection, I register **E** in **SPLIT** that results in creating **SPLIT_E** inside. In the same time, this check uniqueness if we didn't register double-time **E**.

The problem is:

- the **E** entity can be in 30k in one split and more (for now, I know be 100k in later future)
- [validation on uniqueness should be made by AR by this source](https://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/10/28/Uniqueness-validation-in-CQRS-Architecture)

In consequence, we iterate over the whole collection inside **SPLIT**, to check if **E** is uniquely assigned. This is correct by DDD. As we use PHP + `Doctrine` (ORM), this kills the process, because need a lot of memory iteration on the whole collection. Also, it is a slow process as we iterate on big collection each time to check uniqueness.
Also, we have one command that results in pull whole collection **E** and save after each register of **E** in **SPLIT**.

One of the optimizations needs to give up check uniqueness in **SPLIT**. Another one is to call `flush` & `clear` from `doctrine` (infrastructure) inside `handler` class, that breaks a little rule, that `Application/UseCases` should be only dependent on `Domain`. In the result, we save update of **SPLIT** in DB multiple times in one process. Then we can't make the whole command in one transaction. Another problem is we want to check progress. As we break the rule for CQRS and commit multiple times transaction, we have current progress. Without that, you could see only on start and of splitting process.

## Propositions

This was inspired by another question:

- [Aggregate root optimization with nested objects & big collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811343/aggregate-root-optimization-with-nested-objects-big-collections)
- [Implementing Associations With References and Repositories in Domain-Driven Design (DDD)](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/24/implementing-associations-with-references-or-repositories-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/)

As to follow the rule, to [don't create AR in handlers](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/) I thought to **SPLIT** shouldn't create **SPLIT_E** not as an inside entity, but another **SPLIT_E_AR** AR. As we want to hold rule to a single transaction, per AR, we should split register command per each **E**. Then we will have in one command: pull **E**, pass to `register(E)` and save **SPLIT** and save **SPLIT_E_AR**. As this is allowed by the mentioned article. 
Generating 30k (or much more) commands for the queue is a scary vision.

Next problem is, how we define current progress? 
My only options are when we generate **SPLIT**, we need also store inside ID of all planned **E** with a flag if the given entity was registered (was created **SPLIT_E** based on that). Based on that, we can check uniqueness. This leads to store the whole collection, but now not as big entities, but as a collection of Value objects (VO). 
If memory and process will be more optimized? I didn't test that for now. In the read model, I pull that collection and very easily calculate progress.

In general, I don't see more takeaways from this proposition - only much more code to write, than the original solution.

#### Spin-off

To extends this problem, I want to tell you, that **GROUP** have **A** entity that contains rules. Therefore we also want to pass that to with **GROUP_A**, the **E** was assigned in given **SPLIT**. Then we need to store it as a new entity, to not break the boundaries of AR. Then we need **GROUP_A** copy as **SPLIT_A**.

If we have the original approach, then we can easily design relationship inside **SPLIT**. If we won't go with the given proposition, then **SPLIT_A** should be in **SPLIT** and **SPLIT_E_AR** would need hold `ID` to **SPLIT_A**. I don't know if this not break rules of boundaries of AR?

## Question

How to model those models to be fair with rules of DDD, CQRS and have good optimization in ORM?

## Summary

This problem is much more complicated. I tried to describe the core problem.

Thanks :)

#### Reads

- [How should rules for Aggregate Roots be enforced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466757/how-should-rules-for-aggregate-roots-be-enforced?rq=1)
- [validation on uniqueness should be made by AR by this source](https://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/10/28/Uniqueness-validation-in-CQRS-Architecture)
- [don't create AR in handlers](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)
- [Aggregate root optimization with nested objects & big collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811343/aggregate-root-optimization-with-nested-objects-big-collections)
- [Implementing Associations With References and Repositories in Domain-Driven Design (DDD)](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/24/implementing-associations-with-references-or-repositories-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/)

#### Plan to read

- [Effective Aggregate Design](https://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/)